# How to get an image of an SD card with only the actual partitions, and not the empty space after them?

Tags: linux, sd-card, mobile-phone

I have a 16 GB SD card (specifically a bootable Mobian SD card for a PinePhone) with two partitions, totalling 6 GB. The remaining space is unallocated. How can I get a 6 GB image of the SD card?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, with a slightly fragile command, to copy the first section of a drive to an image file as requested. There are, however, a few things to be aware of:

- As direct access to the device files from the command line is needed, the entire command has to be executed as `root` (As in, `sudo su` command before using the solution.)
- The backup partition table, if it's a GPT partition table, *will **NOT** be copied*.
- The "trick" depends on the partition table being complete - the unallocated space mentioned *really is* unallocated, not some partition you just don't want to copy.
- The partition, or partitions, are collected at the front. If they have a gap, that gap will be copied.
- It depends on your system having both the `fdisk` command (likely) and the `bc` command (possible) installed. Both are standard and can be installed from your default repo if needed.
- The image file will be owned by root, so you'll have to `chown` it if you need the user to have full access.

Here is the full command, broken in lines to make it easier to read

```
dd if=/dev/sdx of=Mobian.img\
    bs="$(fdisk -l /dev/sdx | grep sectors | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f6)"\
    count="$(echo "$(fdisk -o end -l /dev/sdx | tail -1) + 1"|bc)"\
    status=progress
```

The breakdown:

First off, the `/dev/sdx` needs to be changed to reflect the correct device name, unless you happen to have 23 other, prior attached, disks.

The first line is the expected `dd` command, with the device name and file name being set to your current needs.

The second line sets the block size for `dd` to the sector size of the SD card. It is almost certainly 512 bytes. If you are 100% certain it is 512, you can replace the line with `bs=512`. If you want to be safe, and keep the command usable on any device in the future, keep the extra stuff there. The operation is:

- `fdisk -l /dev/sdx` report data about the device
- `grep sector` 'sector' appears twice in the output
- `tail -1` only get the last line with 'sector' in it
- `cut -d' ' -f6` using spaces between fields only get the 6th field (the sector size in bytes)

The third line tells `dd` how many 'blocks' of size `bs=` to copy. Again, if you happen to know exactly what that number is, use it instead of the command. For 'future-proofing' I've kept the full command, again:

```
- `fdisk -o end -l /dev/sdx` list the partition information about the device, and only output the ending sector ID of each `-o end`
- `tail -1` it don't matter how many there are, we only need the last sector of the last partion.
- `echo "... + 1" | bc` add one to the last sector ID. Uses the `bc` command, which is in integers unless told otherwise. Sectors are numbered from zero, to to copy sector #10 we have to copy 10 + 1 sectors (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

The fourth line is for entertainment value. A good card, speed class 10, is going to take nearly 4 minutes to read you 6 Gig of data. the `status=progress` option to `dd` will cause updates to the terminal as it make "progress". Otherwise you'll just have a termial waiting on the command to finish, with what will feel like forever.

Final: If you know for sure that what you're copying is bog-standard, with properly aligned partitions and exactly 6 GiB, you could use the simple command of:

```
dd if=/dev/sdx of=Mobian.img bs=1048576 count=6145 status=progress
```

Of course, once they make a new image and you switch to that, all bets are off with the short version. The original up top will keep working. It'll also work for other 'images' you might have the need to copy later.

Bonus:

If you happen to not like `dd` for whatever reason, you can use the same number gathering steps and apply the `head` command instead:

```
head -c $(\echo "\
    "$(fdisk -l /dev/sdx | grep sectors | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f6)" *\
    ("$(fdisk -o end -l /dev/sdx | tail -1)" + 1)" | bc)\
    /dev/sdx > Mobian.img
```

As a one-liner:

`head -c $(\echo " "$(fdisk -l /dev/sdx | grep sectors | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f6)" * ("$(fdisk -o end -l /dev/sdx | tail -1)" + 1)" | bc) /dev/sdx > Mobian.img'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the linux dd command. You have the choice to read out both partitions individually and concatenating them thereafter or to do some calculations to determine the last sector of the second partition. You would then run the dd command using the bs (block size) and count (number of blocks) parameters to have the copy end at the end of the second partition.

Comment: There would probably be no point in concatenating them unless a new partition table is also concatenated though. (And in the case of GPT, there's also the backup GPT that should be at the end of the image.) (Also note that the data in the "gaps" will be lost, such as grub's core.img in the case of "MBR+BIOS".)

Comment: By the way it's also totally possible to do it on the fly. I mean something like `cat /dev/sdX{1,2} > dump.img` or `(dd if=/dev/sdX1; dd if=/dev/sdX2) > dump.img`